# something similar to zip ties? (heavy duty)

Tags: roof, hardware, fastener, fastening, cover

I have a dog kennel and framed roof with a tarp.

Traditional bungee straps for the tarp have too much give and stretch out over time. Additionally, any snow load causes the tarp to deform and dump snow into the kennel.

I tried 150lb tensile strength zip ties to keep the tarp taught, however these don't seem strong enough as I keep finding some on the ground from snapping in the cold.

Is there a either a much stronger zip tie (250lb tensile strength) or an alternative to attaching the tarp to the roof frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

250lb cable ties are made, yes. "industrial zip ties" seemed to be a pretty good search string for finding sources.

Probably more the cold making the plastic brittle than the basic strength of the zip tie. They do make "large, industrial" zip ties (I've seen 3 feet long and half an inch wide, and they probably go bigger) but you'll probably get better cost and service from rope, and learning to tie a "trucker's hitch."